# Angular2 compile to bin path?

Tags: angular

So I just started looking at Angular 2 and completed the quickstart. I noticed that when I run the project, it compiles all the .ts files to javascript and those are stored in the same dir as the .ts files, in the app folder.

Why is there not a bin folder (or equal) storing all the "compiled" .js files? There will clearly be a mess of files in the app folder when extending the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a quickstart tutorial, which doesn't want to go too deep into advanced configurations. For your own project you can of course configure additional output directories for the TS compiler (in the tsconfig.json):

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./bin"
}
```